# torsion formula for a parametric space curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I managed to prove 
$$ k(t) = \frac{ | a^{\prime} \times a^{\prime \prime} | }{ | a^{\prime} | ^3 } $$
for a regular parametric curve $a : I \to R^3 $ where $k(t)$ stands for its curvature but I am stucked in proving

$$ \tau (t) = \frac{( a^{\prime} \times a^{\prime \prime} ) \cdot a^{\prime \prime \prime }}{ |a^{\prime} \times a^{\prime \prime} | ^2 } $$

Can I ask anybody to give me any hint or reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: presumably you have been using the Frenet-Serret formulas. can you give some idea where you are stuck?

Comment: it seems for me that Frenet-Serret formulas solve the problems when $t$ stands for the arc length parameter but I'm stuck in how to exploit that formula for the case of general parameters.. Could you suggest me any hint for approach?

Comment: OK ...it's very similar but with extra factors throughout because of the chain rule. I will get back to you...

Answer (score 0):

It's going to take too long to type it all out in MathJax, so I have uploaded two photos of the derivations of the formulas for curvature and torsion.enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

reparametrize $\alpha (t)$ with $\beta (s(t))$ where $s=s(t)$ is its arc length. Direct computation gives

$$\alpha (t) = \beta (s(t)) $$
$$ \dot{ \alpha } (t) = \hat{T} (s(t)) \dot{ s(t) } $$
$$ \ddot{\alpha}(t) = k( s(t) ) \hat{N} (s(t)) \dot{s}(t) ^2 + \hat{T} (s(t)) \ddot{s} (t) $$
$$\dddot{\alpha} (t) = (\dddot{s}(t) - k^2 (s(t)) \dot{s} (t)^3 ) \hat{T} ( s(t)) + (3 k (s(t)) \dot{s} (t) \ddot{s}(t) + k^{\prime} (s(t)) \dot{s} (t) ^3 ) \hat{N} ( s(t) ) - k( s(t)) \tau (s(t)) \dot{s} (t) ^3 \hat{B} (s(t)) $$

The rest is simple calculation.